# c++ vector exploitation as shared variable

Tags: c++, data-manipulation

everybody!

I tried to search an already existing thread about this but I couldn't find one. In case you are aware of the one that answers my question, please share it.

Well, here is my problem.
I am writing a program where each object stores all the information relative to itself in variables inside its class (e.g. std::vector).
Unfortunately, since I'm using a library developed by other people, some operations can be performed only on single std::vectors. Thus, the way I found to "solve" the problem is to stack all the single vectors inside each object into a big std::vector, then process this "stack" and finally "split" the updated information back inside each object.

My first approach to stack the information was to allocate a new empty std::vector and then, going through all the object, push_back all the information in each single vector. To unstack, instead, I created a new empty sub-vector, went through the stack, pushed back the information that I needed and then assigned the sub-vector to the related body.

To try to speed up the process, I thought that I might have used the functions std::vector.insert and std::copy.
Unfortunately, this seems to have slowed down even more the whole program.

So, do you know any way that could help me making my code run faster?

Example:

```
class MyObject
{
   protected:
   std::vector m_vector;
   unsigned int m_vector_begin;
   unsigned int m_vector_end;

   public:
   MyObject(std::vector &vector)
   {
      m_vector = vector;
   }

   ~MyObject();

   std::vector get_vector()
   {
       return m_vector;
   }

   void set_vector(std::vector &vector)
   {
       m_vector = vector;
   }

   void set_vector_begin(unsigned int &index)
   {
      m_vector_begin = index;
   }

   unsigned int get_vector_begin()
   {
      return m_vector_begin;
   }

   // same for m_vector_end
};


class MyManipulator
{
   protected:
   std::vector<MyObject*> m_obj_list;

   public:
   MyManipulator(std::vector<MyObject*> &obj_list)
   {
      m_obj_list = obj_list;
   }

   ~MyManipulator();

   std::vector build_stack()
   {
      std::vector stack, array;

      for(unsigned int index_obj = 0; index_obj < m_obj_list.size(); ++index_obj)
      {
          array = m_obj_list[index_obj]->get_vector();

          m_obj_list[index_obj]->set_vector_begin(stack.size());
          stack.insert(stack.end(), array.begin(), array.end());
          m_obj_list[index_obj]->set_vector_end(stack.size());
      }
      return stack;
   }

   void unstack_vector(std::vector &stack)
   {
      std::vector array;

      for(unsigned int index = 0; index < m_obj_list.size(); ++index)
      {
         array = std::vector(stack.begin()+m_obj_list[obj_index]->get_vector_begin(),
                             stack.begin()+m_obj_list[obj_index]->get_vector_end());

         m_obj_list[obj_index]->set_vector(array);
      }
   }

   void do_some_stuff(std::vector &input, std::vector &output)
   {
      unstack_vector(input);

      // Does operations with the information saved in
      // the objects and builds output
   }
};


int main
{
   std::vector<MyObject*> obj_list;

   std::vector vect_ini;
   // initialise vect_ini

   MyObject* Obj1 = new MyObject*(vect_ini);
   obj_list.push_back(Obj1);

   // change values to vect_ini

   MyObject* Obj2 = new MyObject(vect_ini);
   obj_list.push_back(Obj2);

   MyManipulator* Manip = new MyManipulator(obj_list);

   std::vector stack_in  = Manip->build_stack();
   std::vector stack_out = std::vector(stack_ini.size());

   for(unsigned int index_loop = 0; index_loop < N; ++index_loop)
   {
      Manip->do_some_stuff(stack_in, stack_out);

      stack_in = stack_out;
   }

   return 0;
};
```

I hope this helps

Comment: It's very difficult to provide any form of advice without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Do you have any profiling data that shows which parts have slowed the most?

Comment: Can you demonstrate with some code?  Like a picture, code is worth a thousand words.

Comment: @NathanOliver unless it's 1000 words of code, then it can start going down in value!

Comment: This doesn't compile. std::vector< of what? >

Comment: @KennyOstrom of anything. Actually I use templated classes. Try with std::vector<double>

Comment: You don't understand. MCVE. I could go through fixing all the incorrect variable names, deliberately wrong syntax, missing accessor functions, but I'm not going to do that, because it's your responsibility. How would I even know which mistakes are in this post and which are in your real code? :)

Comment: I will note that you construct a copy of all the data for every "do_some_stuff" operation. That one is obviously by design, but it is a performance hit. I'd rather have working code before I check it for any more unintended extra copies. (Performance issues with std containers are usually due to making temporary copies you didn't intend, and it's much easier to find those as they happen in working code.)

Comment: @KennyOstrom There are no mistakes in this code nor in my real code, simply because finding errors is not the topic of my thread.
I just showed an example of the solution that I am using now to handle the problem I have. My real interest is in being taught about alternative ways of handling this kind of problem/data, if anybody knows one.

Comment: When you profile, what percentage of time is spent in build_stack and unstack_vector?

Comment: A couple of observations: you don't need to mess with where each vector begins and ends, you can compute that from their respective lengths. You can avoid a lot of copying by having an interface that accepts iterators instead of copying vectors. (e.g. `length = m_obj_list[obj_index]->length(); m_obj_list[obj_index]->set(current_result_iterator, current_result_iterator + length); current_result_iterator += length;`)

Comment: I am totally new to profiling in c++.
Anyway, I ran a simulation using valgrind and I get this.

stack_vector: Incl = 49.18, Self = 0.0; Called = 7812.

For build_stack everything is basically 0.

Comment: @molbdnilo Interesting. But would you write that inside the method do_some_stuff? Would the initial iterator be current_result_iterator = stack.begin()?